# Unable to extract images properly from a 'YUV' raw file using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, frame, yuv, bit-depth

I have a YUV file, I need to extract all the frames from the video file. The problem is the pixel depth of frames are 11 bit/pixel.

But most of the pixel format options are either 16 bit or 12 bit. I am looking for gray scale format with 11 bit/pixel.

Currently I run the command line:

```
ffmpeg -video_size 448x512 -r 25 -pixel_format gray -i MR.yuv outp
ut-%d.png
```

checked for gray, gray16be, for both the output frame captured is distorted. Is there any method to extract frames at 11bit/pixel depth?[Customised]

[original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQf7C.png),[gray16be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHV6O.png)
Regards,
Prajwal

Comment: If it's padded, as likely, then you can use the lut or geq filter to rescale the input values. What's the chroma sampling used? Can you post a short sample?.

Comment: @Mulvya The sampling method is 4:0:0, with 11bit/pixel. When I view this setting in PYUV player the resulting frames seen in video are of optimum quality. Now i want to extract the same frames, using ffmpeg but I am getting distorted images.

Comment: What's the resolution and file size for 1 frame? Can you attach one?

Comment: @Mulvya Resolution of each frame is 448x512.

Comment: Need a raw sample.

Answer (score 0):

Any YUV file with a bitdepth between 9 and 16 will actually be stored as 16-bits (the unused bits will be padded with 0s). Unless your source file was generated by a weird software which packed the bits, but I doubt it.

Have you tried `gray16le` ? It's much more common than `gray16be`.

P.S : for command line ffmpeg questions, it's recommended to ask them on superuser.com rather than stackoverflow.

Comment: Yes I have tried with gray16le, the results are bad, I get black image in all the frames.

Comment: as Mulvya said, we're gonna need a sample because I'm out of ideas as is.

Comment: I have attached original frame and gray16le frame.

Comment: I was more hoping for the .yuv file itself, or a chunk of it. Sorry, can't really do anyting out of those pngs :P . Just curious, did you have to input parameters into that yuv reader, or did it automatically figure out how to read the file ?

Comment: I did input the parameters (manual setting). For the .yuv file, give me some time, the file cannot be shared, need to ask permission for the same.

Comment: Ok, try `ffmpeg -video_size 448x512 -framerate 25 -pixel_format gray16le -bits_per_raw_sample 11 -i MR.yuv outp
ut-%d.png`. Also, with `gray16le`.

Comment: ffmpeg -video_size 448x512 -framerate 25 -pixel_format gray16le -bits_per_raw_sample 11 -i MR.yuv outp ut-%d.png   this cmd line also doesn't work, the results are the same. distortion in output image. Well according to me -pixel_format will override bits_per_raw_sample so the ouput obtained is same. Well I have no idea how is raw CT file of 11/12 bits/pixel used in reality. There has to be some solution.